# select all objects in bounding box in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm using the excellent code provided in [threex](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2012/01/17/dom-events-in-3d-space/) to allow me to capture clicks on various objects in my scene, which allows me to select them. This works with no issue.

I'd like to extend the selection functionality, where the user can draw a selection box(working), and I can detect all the objects in the scene which are rendered in this selection.

Looking at threex / three, the general `onclick` algorithm seems to be:

- project mouse co-ords to `Ray`
- using `ray.intersectObjects(scene)`, it tests each object in the scene for ray
  intersection

This works for a single '1D' ray in the system, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to modify it to work with a selection box.

Before I attempt to extend this mechanism to work with a selection frustum, is there an alternate / existing facility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is no, there is no such existing facility.

I would not use `Raycaster.intersects()` for this.

Probably the easiest thing to do is to assign a 2D `screenCoords` property to each object, and set it equal to the screen projection of the object's world position. Search this site for how to do that.

Then, consider as selected, those objects whose `screenCoords` are inside the selection box in screen space.

If you need complete containment, then you have to either do the above for each vertex, or use something like a bounding sphere as an approximation.

three.js r.58

Comment: Thanks for this answer, @WestLangley. Would you be able to go into more detail? I'm not sure entirely sure what you mean...

Comment: @Detuned Sorry, I do not know what you don't understand. I suggest you post a question on https://discourse.threejs.org if you are unable to understand these concepts yourself.

Comment: Let me try to layout what I do understand and parts that I'm unclear about:

1) Each object has a screenCoords position (x, y) that is the unprojected coordinate of the model
2) Given a boundary box, check whether the object's unprojected coords are within that box.

Why wouldn't you use some k-d tree/octree model to do this? Would you be able to do this at a vertex level rather than an object level? I need to select all vertices in a given boundary box.

Thank you, @WestLangley